# set Android alarm - Reminder app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, alarmmanager

I follow [this example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/) to set up alarm.

This is the **MainActivity** class extends with Droidgap

```
@SuppressLint({ "JavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" }) public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
//CordovaWebView cwv;
final static public long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
final static public long TWENTY_SECONDS = ONE_SECOND * 20;
public PendingIntent pi;
public BroadcastReceiver br;
public AlarmManager am;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

    WebView webView =new WebView(this);
    //enabling javascript call to native code
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setClickable(true);
    //Give name to interface class, "Reminder" will call through javascript
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MainActivity(), "Reminder");

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
     setContentView(webView);        

}
```

This work fine, its set alarm and fire properly,

```
 @Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    setup();
am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 
            TWENTY_SECONDS, pi ); //This code works
}
```

While i try to invoke another method have same code through javascript its give NullPointerException, This is my JavascriptInterface,

```
 @JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String mssg) {

     Log.v("AlrmMNG", am.toString());//Even this log is not working
        am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 
                TWENTY_SECONDS, pi );

Log.v("Alarm end", "Alarm set");
}
```

This is the **logcat**,

```
03-05 12:25:58.330: E/AndroidRuntime(3444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-05 12:55:59.710: W/System.err(3640): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 12:55:59.710: W/System.err(3640):     at com.agrando.reminder_level1.MainActivity.showToast(MainActivity.java:67)
03-05 12:55:59.710: W/System.err(3640):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-05 12:55:59.720: W/System.err(3640):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
03-05 12:55:59.730: W/System.err(3640):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-05 12:55:59.730: W/System.err(3640):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-05 12:55:59.730: W/System.err(3640):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-05 12:55:59.830: I/chromium(3640): [INFO:CONSOLE(25)] "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (25)
```

**I tried this in several different methods but same result.( I didn't add setup() code in here, you can find it from link given above.) Please help **

****Here is the [link to project files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jjoyqDycUFN1kyX3Fjc2NURjA/edit?usp=sharing) ****

Comment: `new MainActivity()` is wrong can't instantiate activity class

Comment: @Raghunandan - Sure, but i tried this using "new test(this)" class, but same result. in test class i have showToast() method. test class extends MainActivity

Comment: @Raghunandan - test class is just a class extends MainActivity that have showToast() method, normal code in this mehtod working fine,Except this. i can call other class methods and retrieve values from them, but accessing system resources like alarm manager did doesn't allow

Answer (score 1):

`am` instance of `AlarmManager` is `null` before you forget to initialize it before using so do it as:

```
am=(AlarmManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Do i need to initiate it again and again before i setup alarm ?, i did it initiate in in the onStart().

Comment: @saw : you mean you have initialize it inside `setup` ? then ok no need to initialize it Again.

Comment: @saw : but either am or pi is null and also create an separate or inner class for passing to addJavascriptInterface method instead of create MainActivity Object

Comment: I add setup(); into showToast(String mssg) method. but its not working
This Log.v("AlrmMNG", am.toString()); also not log any....

Comment: using separate class also give the same result !!!, my api level is 19 anything wrong with that ?